# I tried many times to post a question on **Mathoverflow** but ...?

Tags: support, asking-questions

My Question seems to silly, but really I want to fix this problem
I tried many times to post a question on **mathoverflow and their meta** but the page becomes static when I click "Post your question", really I don't know why(I completed all fields). 
I notice that
(1) There is no suggestions for tags
(2) During writing, there is no display

Comment: Since this is question about MathOverflow, it would probably better suited on [their meta](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions). If you cannot ask there, perhaps some of the moderators here would be able to help you move your question there?

Comment: Also, i tried their meta and i faced the same problem

Comment: Since MathOverflow is now [part of SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12630/since-when-does-mathoverflow-become-one-of-se-family), I find it rather surprising that two sites which are running on the same engine and they are part of the same system behave differently.

Comment: Me too, @MartinSleziak

Comment: I posted many questions and answers on Mathematics SE

Comment: Actually, since this seems to be an isolated problem with the technology, I feel that the best way to raise this is in fact visiting the "contact us" link on MathOverflow which will send an e-mail to the moderators _and_ developers, the latter of whom being the people most likely to help you with the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try a hard refresh of the page, and clear your browser cache or try using a different browser. This looks like your copy of the SE Javascript is bad on MO.

Comment: Thank you this fix the problem